# Opening .grd from R in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, format

How to open .grd raster layers in QGIS (or any other GIS)?

I have looked through previous questions, but not found any answer. My raster layers are outputs from running bfastSpatial in R and I can't seem to open them in QGIS. I have also been unsuccessful in converting the format to .tif so I am hoping there is some other option.

Answer (score 5):

There is no gdal driver for the native format of the raster package (gri + grd), that is why you cannot directly open it in QGIS. One workaround to open data in QGIS without duplicating them is to create an additional header file using the `hdr()` function of the raster package.

```
library(raster)

b <- brick('/path/to/file.grd')
hdr(b, format = 'ENVI')
```

Point to the `.gri` file when opening with QGIS

Comment: Please, could you specify, what exactly means "create an additional header file"? I tried with a text file with .hdr extension, but it does not work. Any other hint?

Answer (score 1):

Use `raster` package to convert your files to .tif before loading them in QGIS. I will use a reproducible example from the package example:

```
library(bfastSpatial)

srdir <- dirout <- file.path(dirname(rasterTmpFile()), 'bfmspatial_2')
dir.create(dirout, showWarning=FALSE)

# Get the directory where the Landsat archives are stored
dir <- system.file('external', package='bfastSpatial')

# Run the batch line
processLandsatBatch(x=dir, pattern=glob2rx('*.zip'), outdir=dirout, srdir=srdir, delete=TRUE, vi='ndvi', mask='fmask', keep=0, overwrite=TRUE)

list <- list.files(dirout, pattern=glob2rx('*.grd'), full.names=TRUE)
```

The above code creates a .grd image. Now use raster package to convert files.

```
r <- raster::raster(list[[1]])

raster::writeRaster(r,filename = "image_name", format = "GTiff")
```

Also, you can create a loop to automate all the process.

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
  r <- raster::raster(list[[i]])
  name <- gsub(pattern = ".*bfmspatial_2/",replacement = "", r@file@name) # your folder here (pattern)
  name <- gsub(pattern = ".grd",replacement = "", name)
  raster::writeRaster(r,filename = name, format = "GTiff") 
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: I have tried but I get this error : Fehler in .getGDALtransient(x, filename = filename, options = options, : filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE

Comment: I just replaced ".*bfmspatial_2/" with my folder

Comment: Did you list files? Paste a part of your results to see what happens.